# WYSIWYG CSS editor that can convert XML via XSLT to HTML

Tags: windows, web-development, css, xml, wysiwyg

Can anyone recommend a good WYSIWYG CSS editor for Windows?

**Main requirement:** My files are in XML, not HTML, so it needs to XSLT the XML first, to produce the "HTML" that then can be "played around with" in the editor.

Preferably free, but also would like to know what other options there are.

Also of interest would be browser extensions that could help "monkey" visually with the CSS, like changing colors visually.

Comment: Converting the XML to HTML with a separate tool isn’t possible in your case? Because then you could use just any CSS editor, right? And just to be clear, do you really need a CSS-only editor (as your title suggests) or should the editor also be able to change the HTML (like the tag you added suggested)?

Comment: yeah I gave up, now I'm using Eclipse - it can do the transformation and I can view it in a browser inside Eclipse. It's not a WYSIWYG solution but my guess is any that exist wouldn't be free

Comment: Like http://www.altova.com/de/stylevision.html?